# How to read multiple data within the MySQL Table

Tags: php, mysql

```
  ID    _   PAGE            _   TOKEN
  _____________________________________________
  1    _    Page Name       _   IPADRESS#tokenID@BrowserName 34
  ..
```

Example Data:

```
  IPADRESS#tokenID@BrowserName 34
  123.123.123.123#abcde987654321@Mozilla 34(Version)
```

How do I read the token table separately?
I want to like this:

```
  <?php 
  echo row['ip'];
  echo row['browserName'];
  echo row['browserVersion']; ?>
```

Is it possible this way?

Comment: Take a look at regular expressions.

Comment: you can specify a delimiter for tokens (that'll never appear within a token) and use php's `expldoe()` to divide a token into components

Comment: @Ejay Thank you for ideal, I use to `multiexplode()` but print: `Array ( [0] => 123.123.123.123 [1] => xzszont4ja9vn2915ittwvfzvgyzaor [2] => chrome [3] => 34 )` (?)

Comment: @Ejay I did! Thank you for ideal again :)

Answer (score 0):

**I did:**

```
function multiexplode ($delimiters,$string) {

$ready = str_replace($delimiters, $delimiters[0], $string);
$launch = explode($delimiters[0], $ready);
return  $launch;
}

$text = $row['token'];
$exploded = multiexplode(array("#","@"," "),$text);
print_r($exploded);

echo $exploded[0].'</br>';
echo $exploded[1].'</br>';
echo $exploded[2].'</br>';
echo $exploded[3].'</br>';
```